# Same video on a large number of pages in video sitemap

Tags: seo, video, video-sitemap

I have a forum and wrote a script that automatically detects the topic that is being discussed and serves up a related video.

I'm thinking of adding that video inside the video sitemaps. My concern is that it may look spammy to Google. For example 1000 pages will have the same exact video.

So the question is: Is it safe to show the same video on many different pages on the site.

Comment: Yes, it is fine to repeat content throughout the site, but you need to ensure the those pages have some unique content, otherwise Google consider it both duplicate and thin, subject to a Panda Slap.